# extra spaces written in r+ mode

Tags: c, file, tdm-gcc

In the code below, extra spcaes (may be around 300 space) are getting appended if I write data after seeking the file pointer to the start position after the line

```
fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET);
```

If I comment second fputs() function call, there is no issue. 
Also the inputted data is not getting appended at the end, instead only spaces are getting appended.
I am unable to identify the problem.

I am using TDM-GCC-64 compiler.

For testing purpose, file1.txt had contents "Welcome to You All" at the beginning.
Inputted data: "Today"
Output after execution of the program: "Todayme to You All" followed by many spaces.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch;
    char data[50];
    fp1=fopen("file1.txt", "r+");
    if(fp1==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in Opening the file\n");
        return(0);
    }

    printf("Read and Write Mode. The data in the file is\n");
    while((ch=getc(fp1))!=EOF)
    {
        putc(ch,stdout);
    }
    // Write some data at the end of the file
    printf("\nEnter some data to be written to the file\n");
    gets(data);
    fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_END);
    fputs(data,fp1);
    fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET);
    fputs(data,fp1);
    printf("data in file after write operation is\n");
    while((ch=getc(fp1))!=EOF)
    {
        putc(ch,stdout);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just pointing out to avoid such usage and return type of getchar is int. The return value your catching is in char ch.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get "Today" inserted both in the start of and the end of the file. No extra spaces at all. BTW: Before printing the file the last time, you should add a `fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET);` if you want to print the whole file.

Comment: OT: Never use `gets`

Comment: @4386427 Could you tell me what compiler you are using? My friend also said he is not getting the problem in MinGW

Comment: gcc version 6.3.1 and "gcc -Wall code.c"

Comment: OT: `char ch;` ==> `int ch;`

Comment: @4386427 Added fseek(fp1,0,SEEK_SET); before printing. Surprisingly the problem got fixed. But I feel reading the file should not alter the file contents. Is it undefined behavior if fp is not moved to the beginning before the read!! Alternatively I tried by closing fp and opening in "r" mode and there is no issue even in this case. This probably confirms the undefined behavior if we read a file with fp at the end (may be in some of the modes)

Comment: the function `gets()` has been depreciated for many years and completely removed in the latest versions of C.  Your compiler should have told you about this.  Suggest using `fgets()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the fine print in the [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) documentation:

> In update mode ('+'), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos or rewind, and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to fseek, fsetpos or rewind, unless the input operation encountered end of file.

Reading and writing might be buffered, but still share a single file position. Switching modes without alerting the runtime (`fseek`) could mess up the buffering. Like you have noticed!